# grep includes wrong results from rsync output

Tags: bash, grep, rsync

I have a script to backup some files using `rsync`.
Because I don't want the full output detail, I use `grep` to select only the summary output that I want to see:

`rsync -PaSh --stats --delete -e 'ssh -p XXXX -i key' /source/ user@X.X.X.X:/destination/ 2>> output.txt |`**`grep -e 'Number of regular files' -e 'Total transferred' -e 'bytes/sec'`**`>> output.txt`

This returns a nice summary, e.g.:

```
Number of regular files transferred: 73
Total transferred file size: 165.68M bytes
sent 3.79M bytes  received 207.71K bytes  103.89K bytes/sec
```

One of the backup locations is a Firefox profile where the files frequently change as a browse.

This means that `rsync` throws out errors when a file can no longer be found: `file has vanished`.

I want to exclude this error, but for some reason the error message keeps being shown even though it's not included in `grep`:

```
file has vanished: "file1"
file has vanished: "file2"
file has vanished: "file3"
rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
Number of regular files transferred: 73
Total transferred file size: 165.68M bytes
sent 3.79M bytes  received 207.71K bytes  103.89K bytes/sec
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Then why do you do `2>> output.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe `|` redirects standard output `stdout` to standard input `stdin` of other processes.

However, in parallel to standard output there is also standard error `stderr` stream. `stdout` is on file descriptor 1, `stderr` is on file descriptor 2.

To redirect file descriptor 2 to file descriptor 1, do:

```
 rsync .... 2>&1 | grep ...
```

More info could be found at various places over the net, probably the documentation for this is in [posix shell redirection](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07):

> [...] These numbers are called "file descriptors". The values 0, 1, and 2 have special meaning and conventional uses and are implied by certain redirection operations; they are referred to as standard input, standard output, and standard error, respectively. Programs usually take their input from standard input, and write output on standard output. Error messages are usually written on standard error. [...]

Comment: Indeed, this is the answer. Thank you.